# Java ArrayList: Adding primitive type or its wrapper-class: What's the difference?

Tags: java, arraylist, primitive

imagine the following ArrayList in Java:

```
ArrayList<Integer> u = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I want to know if there is a difference when adding new values either as primitive types or as wrapper-classes:

```
u.add(new Integer(12));
u.add(12);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I am feeling lucky now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `u.add(12);` compiler rewrites it to `u.add(Integer.valueOf(12));` which is more efficient than `u.add(new Integer(12));`
Read more on official tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference in `add` due to auto boxing/unboxing. Actually don't do `new Integer(12)` but `Integer.valueOf(12)` since it uses the flighweight pattern and reuses known objects (in the range -128, 127). So no new object would be created.

There is a difference in `remove` for example.
Since if you intent to call `remove(Object)` calling `remove(5)` will call `remove(int index)` and this perhaps is not what you want.
You should do `remove((Integer)5)` if you want to remove the number `5` or `remove(5)` if you want to remove the fifth element.